# Setting up passwordless ssh failed for all the HAWQ hosts

Tags: hdfs, ambari, hawq

we have 3 node and trying to setup hdfs and pivotal hawq with ambari and i have already enabled passwordless ssh  for all the 3 machines but when i start hawq service i am getting "Setting up passwordless ssh failed for all the HAWQ hosts" this error please help to resolve this issue.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3KH9R.png)

Answer (score 2):

On all of your hosts, edit your /etc/ssh/sshd_config file and change "PasswordAuthentication no" to "PasswordAuthentication yes".  This can be done with sed too.

```
sudo sed -i 's/PasswordAuthentication no/PasswordAuthentication yes/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Then restart sshd on all of the hosts:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/sshd restart
```

Now you can proceed with the installation of HAWQ.  The installation is using a command called gpssh-exkeys.  This process uses password authentication to communicate with the hosts so that it can create and exchange keys for the gpadmin account.  Once the keys have been exchanged, the gpadmin account no longer needs password authentication.

Also, after the installation is complete, you can revert back and disable password authentication if you like.

Lastly, I've asked the PM for HDB at Pivotal to enhance Ambari to do these steps for you automatically.  There is a similar process for iptables being disabled during the installation of Hadoop so this would be like that.  Ambari would enable password authentication, install HDB, and then disable password authentication.